# RegEx to find first Tab in each line in a block of text

Tags: regex

Hi all and thanks in advance,

I need a regex that will land me on the first tab in each line.

For instance

```
Romania RO  ROU 642
Russian Federation  RU  RUS 643
Rwanda  RW  RWA 646
Saint Barthelemy    BL  BLM 652
```

Should be parsed like this

```
Romania[*]  RO  ROU 642
Russian Federation[*]   RU  RUS 643
Rwanda[*]   RW  RWA 646
Saint Barthelemy[*] BL  BLM 652
```

all other tabs in the same line should be ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this but ensure to set a Multi-line option in whichever language you are using:

```
^[^\t]*(\t{1}).*$
```

Comment: The {1} seems like the right approach but it is not working for me. Id this the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes - it means "exactly 1 time". What language are you using? If it's C# for example you'll need to escape the curly-braces `{{1}}`

Comment: I'm trying to clean up some data in TextPad. I would like to use RegEx to do a find/replace. I need to enclose the first part of each line in quotes. I was able to put the quote at the start of the line by searching for `'\n'` and replacing it with `'\n"'`

Comment: I use TextPad. Hit F8 - Find what: `\t\{1\}\(.*\)` and Replace with: `[*]\t\1` - seemed to work for me with your examples above.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go

Pattern

```
(^.*?)(\t)
```

Replace with

```
$1[*]$2
```

Use the modifier that lets ^ and $ match at line breaks.

Let me know if you got any more questions.

Regards, Tom